# how to create session express.js

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express

I run localhost:3000/name/john, create a cookie
then localhost:3000/name to display the cookie
I have a console error "TypeError: Can not read property 'name' of undefined"

look my code

```
 var express = require('express')
     , http = require('http') 
     , path = require('path') ;

var app = express();        

        app.configure(function(){
            app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
            app.use(express.bodyParser()) ;
            app.use(express.methodOverride()) ;
            app.use(app.router);

            app.use(express.cookieParser());  
            app.use(express.session({ secret: 'secret'}));
        }) ;

      app.get('/name/:name', function(req, res){
            res.cookie('name' , req.params.name).send('<p>the cookie <a href="/name">Go here</a></p>') ;
       });

      app.get('/name', function(req, res){
          console.log(req.cookies.name);
          res.send("index");
      });  

    http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
      console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
    });
```

how to solve this problem ? thanks

Comment: are you passing the :name param in your get request? also read this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006190/deal-and-keep-node-js-express-sessions

Comment: I find the solution read the link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645792/node-js-and-express-how-to-read-a-cooke-but-is-undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your app.configure code as below.

```
app.configure(function(){
      app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
      app.use(express.bodyParser()) ;
      app.use(express.methodOverride()) ;
      app.use(express.cookieParser());  
      app.use(express.session({ secret: 'secret'}));
      app.use(app.router);
}) ;
```

Have a look at http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use. Here the problem is with the middleware precedence.